# Solution disappearance responsive navigation after open/close

Tags: javascript, html, css, nav

I asked this before, but still not successful. Hope someone can help me now... In the fiddle you see a responsive menu that has 4 menu-items horizontal inline when it is larger than 1000px. Smaller than 1000px the menu shows a nav-btn (now a RED box!) that onclick shows the menu-items, but when open and close and resize to larger than 1000px the rest of the 3 menu-items don't show up. I did some tests with media queries but i think the solution must be find in the javascript part. Anyone can handle this challenge?

Here the [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/foroloca/wz8vc0yo/4/)

```
$(function() {
$('.nav-btn').click(function(event) {
$('nav ul').fadeToggle(300);
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the problem is that your fadeToggle sets your `nav > ul` to `style="display: none"`. Styles set directly overrides any stylesheets, unless you use !important.

As such, and combining with NMindz answer, try this:

```
@media all and (min-width: 1000px) {
  nav ul { 
    display: block !important;
    top: 60px;
  }
}
```

You could also try a pure css solution that would probably be better. Something like

```
nav ul.show {
    display: block;
}
```

And for the javascript

```
$(function() {
    $('.nav-btn').click(function(event) {
        $('nav ul').toggleClass("show");
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks both work, but how do you get a fadeToggleClass with 300 transition for the javascript version? Which solution is the best one the use you think?

Comment: Well, I tend to prefer having all changes put into css classes, then toggling between various states with css classes through javascript. When using jquery animations, things are put into `style=""`, which will likely not work like you'd like with media based css. The transition is slightly more difficult, as css transition doesn't work on display. However, you could do opacity instead.

Comment: ok so not the media query, do you know how to add a fadeToggleClass does it exist like that because it won't work.

Comment: Sorry, there's no fadeToggleClass function, or anything like it. An element either has a class, or it doesn't. You could look into [css3 transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition.asp), though note that transitions does not work on display properties.

Comment: Ok well than i have to use media query again if the isn't a fade addition in the javascript. I want to have a fade toggle effect. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add a new media query like i did here @ [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/foroloca/wz8vc0yo/4/)

```
@media all and (min-width: 1000px) {
  nav ul { 
    display: block;
    top: 60px;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks but i have to rebuild everything. It must be simple through the javascript something like: `$(window).resize(function(){
  if(w > 1000 && nav.is(':block')) {
    nav.removeAttr('style');}
});`  But i'm not a javascript master...