# Add a fadeIn effect on toggleclass?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fade

I want to add a fadeIn/Out effect on a toggle class when navigation is open and close. Somebody know how? I'm using the toggle class because of a responsive problem i had before when resizing part of the navigation disappeared.

[FIDDLE example](http://jsfiddle.net/foroloca/wz8vc0yo/6/)

```
nav ul.show {
    display: block;
}
```

And for the javascript

```
$(function() {
    $('.nav-btn').click(function(event) {
        $('nav ul').toggleClass("show");
    });
});
```

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/wz8vc0yo/7/ ?

Comment: Thank you for helping! Well i just added a fade, because that is what i want, but now i have the same problem back that i had before: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28394678/solution-disappearance-responsive-navigation-after-open-close)

Comment: After using the nav-btn open and close and when resizing larger than 1000px 3 of the 4 navigation items disappear.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer using css transitions these days over jquery animations. To me that appears more clear and easier to read, since logic and visualization are more separate. In the end the action is not the fading, but the change of state (or class in this case). The fading effect is a pure optic gimmick.

```
nav ul {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 500ms;
}
nav ul.show {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: that works, but just before resizing smaller than 1000px you see the navigation in the vertical way for milliseconds and fadeOut. Is it possible to remove that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wz8vc0yo/17/)

```js
// Show navigation //

$(function() {
    $('.nav-btn').click(function(event) {
       // alert();
         if($('nav > ul').hasClass("show"))
        {
           // alert();
         $('nav > ul').fadeOut(1000, function() { 
           $('nav > ul').removeClass('show');
        });
          
        } else {
            
            //alert('no class');
        $('nav > ul').fadeIn(1000, function() { 
           $('nav > ul').addClass('show'); 
        });
        }

    });
});
```

```css
/************************************************
Site Name: 
Author: 
************************************************/

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 26px;
  color: #222;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased; 
}

:hover {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

strong, b {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 0 25px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 25px 0;
}

p a {
  color: #222;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

p a:visited {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

p a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: #111;
}

.tag {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

/************************************************
Header - Navigation
************************************************/

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: white;
}

/* Navigation */

.nav-btn {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: url(../elements/nav-icon.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center left;
  background-color: red;
}

.nav-btn:hover {
  background: url(../elements/nav-icon-hover.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center left;
  background-color: blue;
}

nav {
    margin: 0 40px;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
   
}

nav li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
}

nav a,
nav li a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #111;
    line-height: 61px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 10px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}

nav a:hover,
nav li:hover a {
    color: #aaa;
}

nav ul.show {
    display: block;
}

/*nav li ul {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

nav li:hover ul {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

nav li ul li {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
}

nav li ul a:hover {
    color: #aaa;
}*/


.col-nav,
.col-25 {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0;
}

/************************************************
Responsives
************************************************/

/*@media all and (min-width: 1601px) {

  .col-25 {
    width: 25%; }

  }

@media all and (min-width: 1201px) and (max-width: 1600px) {

   .col-25 {
    width: 25%; }

  }

@media all and (min-width: 1001px) and (max-width: 1200px) {

  .col-25 {
    width: 25%; }

  }

@media all and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 400px) {

  }
  */
@media all and (min-width: 1000px) {
    .class_test{
        display:block !important;
    }
    .home{
      display:none;
      }
}
@media all and (min-width: 801px) and (max-width: 1000px) {

  .col-25 {
    width: 33.33333%; }
  }

@media all and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 800px) {

  .col-25 {
    width: 50%; }

  }

@media all and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 600px) {

  nav {
    margin: 0 10px;
  }

  #container {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }

  .col-25 {
    width: 100%; }
  }

@media all and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 1000px) {

  nav ul { 
    display: none;
    top: 60px;
  }

  /*nav:hover ul {
    display: block; 
  }*/

  .nav-btn {
  display: block; 
  }

  .home {
  width: 220px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .col-nav {
  width: 100%; }
  }

.nav ul {
    transition: display .3s;
}

.nav ul.show {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
 <nav>
  <div class="col-nav">
   <a href="#" class="nav-btn"></a>
   <a href="#" class="home">Untitled</a>
  </div>
  <ul class="class_test">
   <li class="col-nav"><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
   <li class="col-nav"><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
   <li class="col-nav"><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but after using the nav-btn open and! close and resizing larger than 1000px 3 out of the 4 menu items are gone.

Comment: Now It is Perfect... :)

Comment: There 2 media query states: larger than 1000px you see 4 menu items horizontal inline, smaller than that you see a nav-btn (red box now) and the home 'title'.

Comment: Nothing is changed still the same problem, sorry ;-) thanks for your effort!

Comment: Now please Check may be helpful to you

Comment: Thanks Vrajesh, but can you do it like i see the 4 nav items horizontal: UNTITLED | ITEM1 |  ITEM3 |  ITEM3 | Now untitled is gone ;-) thanks for helping

Comment: please make my answer as solution ..tick right beside my answer ..thx in advance...

Comment: I see what you have done media query: i can also use `$(function() {
    $('.nav-btn').click(function(event) {
        $('nav ul').fadeToggle(300);
    })
});` and media query: nav ul (min-width: 1000px) display: block !important; Lesser code

Comment: you can use it but  you cant hide "HOme" title when screen is larger then 1000px.... :(

Comment: But someone told me javascript approach was better.

Comment: Don't want to hide home at all sorry misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Use [fadeToggle()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_fadetoggle) method in jquery

[you can refer the other methods also here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_fade.asp)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

try this.
http://jsfiddle.net/wz8vc0yo/12/

```
$(function() {
    $('.nav-btn').click(function(event) {
        $('nav ul').fadeToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes that works i know, but it has to do with my previous problem:  
After using the nav-btn open and close and when resizing larger than 1000px 3 of the 4 navigation items disappear. [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28394678/solution-disappearance-responsive-navigation-after-open-close)

Answer (score 0):

jquery:

```
$(#divID).toggleClass('yourClass').fadeOut('slow');
```

Comment: Please consider adding a bit of a preface and/or some context to your answer to prevent the answer from being marked as "low quality" and being deleted.