# Animation onClick - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

This may be a silly question but if you have a function that `onClick` makes a modal appear by moving from `display: none` to `display: block`, is it possible to animate only one portion of the transition.  What I mean by that is can you have it appear "instantly" when it is `display:block` and then `fade-out` as it is taken off screen?

See snippet example below

```js
$(function(){
  $('.square').click(function() {
    $('.modal').toggleClass('showModal');
  });
});
```

```css
.square {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  content: '';
}

.modal {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  display: none;
}

.showModal {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="modal"></div>
```

Comment: Similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28406445/add-a-fadein-effect-on-toggleclass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Simply check if it's currently shown. If yes - use animation. If no - instant action.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    if ($('#div').hasClass('active')) {
      $('#div').slideUp(function() {
        $('#div').removeClass('active').show();
      });
    } else {
      $('#div').addClass('active');
    }
  })
})
```

```css
#div {
  height: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}

#div.active {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Toggle</button>
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: Are you available to answer a question?

Answer (score 1):

There might be an even more graceful way, but I wouldn't use the `.showModal` class to do this.

You can check if the element is set to `display: none;`

- If so, you can change the element's css to `display: block;`
- Else, you can use the jQuery [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) method, which sets the css `display: none` by design.

Try the following snippet:

```js
$(function(){
  $('.square').click(function() {
    if($('.modal').css('display') === 'none'){
     $('.modal').css('display', 'block');
    } else {
     $('.modal').fadeOut();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.square {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  content: '';
}

.modal {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="modal"></div>
```